# SQL Server PIVOT returns only one row

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a simple table of of 2 columns(varchar):

```
name    |occupation
___________________
Sandra  |Medic
Julija  |Actor
Marija  |Actor
Martyna |Manager
Aiste   |Teacher
Kristina|Teacher
Virg    |Teacher
Jurga   |Actor
Justina |Medic
Mia     |Manager
```

I need to build a pivot table that would look something like this:

```
Medic  | Actor | Teacher | Manager |
____________________________________
Justina| Julija| Aiste   | Martyna
Sandra | Marija| Kristina| Mia 
null   | Jurga | Virg    | null
```

I have written this code to return build the pivot:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    [name],
    [occupation]

  FROM employee
) as Results
PIVOT (
  max([name])
  FOR [occupation]
  IN (
    [Medic],
    [Actor],
    [Teacher],
    [Manager]
  )
) AS PivotTable
```

But I get only one row as a result:

```
Medic   |Actor  |Teacher    |Manager
Sandra  Marija  Virginija   Mia
```

Where did I made a mistake? I also can't understand what aggregate function would be more applicable, since rows contain only text(varchar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a `PIVOT` you are aggregating the data and since you are using `MAX()` you're only going to be able to return one value for each of your new columns. In order to return multiple rows in each column, you need some sort of value to force SQL to return multiples. You can do this by using a windowing function like `row_number()`.

#### Sample Data

```
if object_id('yourtable') is not null
    drop table Table1


CREATE TABLE yourtable
    ([name] varchar(8), [occupation] varchar(7))
;
    
INSERT INTO yourtable
    ([name], [occupation])
VALUES
    ('Sandra', 'Medic'),
    ('Julija', 'Actor'),
    ('Marija', 'Actor'),
    ('Martyna', 'Manager'),
    ('Aiste', 'Teacher'),
    ('Kristina', 'Teacher'),
    ('Virg', 'Teacher'),
    ('Jurga', 'Actor'),
    ('Justina', 'Medic'),
    ('Mia', 'Manager')
;
```

If you add `row_number()` and you query the following:

```
select name, occupation,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by occupation order by name) 
from yourtable
```

You'll return the following data:

```
|     name | occupation | rn |
|----------|------------|----|
|   Julija |      Actor |  1 |
|    Jurga |      Actor |  2 |
|   Marija |      Actor |  3 |
|  Martyna |    Manager |  1 |
|      Mia |    Manager |  2 |
|  Justina |      Medic |  1 |
|   Sandra |      Medic |  2 |
|    Aiste |    Teacher |  1 |
| Kristina |    Teacher |  2 |
|     Virg |    Teacher |  3 |
```

By adding the row_number you have another column that you are grouping by with the `PIVOT` function, so your final query will actually become:

```
select Medic, Actor, Teacher, Manager
from 
(
    select name, occupation,
        rn = row_number() over(partition by occupation order by name) 
    from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
    max(name) 
    for occupation in (Medic, Actor, Teacher, Manager)
) pv
```

Which will return the result that you want:

```
|   Medic |  Actor |  Teacher | Manager |
|---------|--------|----------|---------|
| Justina | Julija |    Aiste | Martyna |
|  Sandra |  Jurga | Kristina |     Mia |
|  (null) | Marija |     Virg |  (null) |
```